# Code runs fine sometimes and gives Integer expression expected error sometimes

Tags: bash, shell, cut

I am writing a code to kill my worker if its memory exceeds a given memory threshold. Below is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
memory_usage=`ps -eo size,pid,user,command --sort -size | awk '{ hr=$1/1024 ; printf("%13.2f Mb ",hr) } { for ( x=4 ; x<=NF ; x++ ) { printf("%s ",$x) } print "" }' |cut -d "" -f2 | cut -d "-" -f1 | grep worker | cut -d M -f 1`
echo "Memory usage is ${memory_usage}"
int_memory_usage=${memory_usage%.*}
echo "Int Memory usage is ${int_memory_usage}"
if [ "${int_memory_usage}" -gt 16000 ];
then
    echo "Memory for worker ${memory_usage} above threshold"
    pkill -f "worker"
fi
```

The code works fine most of the time. It gives the following answer:

```
Memory usage is       4282.88 
Int Memory usage is       4282
```

However in some cases it yields the following error:

```
Memory usage is       4261.01 
         0.34 
Int Memory usage is       4261.01 
         0
/home/kill_worker.sh: line 6: [:       4261.01 
     0: integer expression expected
```

Please help me find the issue in the code.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into OOM killer? It's designed to kill low priority processes when running out of memory.

Comment: Clearly the issue is that the massive one-liner at the top is returning a string containing two numbers and some whitespace, including a newline character — Bash can't treat that as an integer so it crashes. But I'd try to find a more direct way to get the current memory use than trying to fix the monster on line 2.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. I added the following line in my code and it started working fine.

```
memory_usage=`echo "${memory_usage}" | head -1`
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the output, `memory_usage` was set to literally

```
      4261.01 
         0.34
```

Therefore, when the next output removes the stuff after the last dot you're still left with

```
      4261.01 
         0
```

which is clearly not an integer. This is caused by getting two lines from some command on the first line.

[@AndrewTaylor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387688/code-runs-fine-sometimes-and-gives-integer-expression-expected-error-sometimes/50387897#comment87791382_50387688) is right, this approach isn't going to work. I would very much recommend reading up on [process management](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out the exact reason why the `ps` command wasn't working fine. Added a fix for now.